# Azure Node.js Web App - how to make service available while it's being updated?

Tags: node.js, azure

I have one Node.js web app running on Azure with 2 configured instances. When I publish my changes, the web app is not available until it recycles approximately for 1 minute.

The question is - how to make one instance available with the older source code, while updating the other instance with the new code? And when one instance is successfully updated, do the same thing for the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your best bet would be to use Azure Deployment slots to stage your deployments and then swap to production.

More information can be found here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

Directly from the article

> Deploying a web app to a slot first and swapping it into production
>   ensures that all instances of the slot are warmed up before being
>   swapped into production. **This eliminates downtime when you deploy your
>   web app**. The traffic redirection is seamless, and no requests are
>   dropped as a result of swap operations. This entire workflow can be
>   automated by configuring Auto Swap when pre-swap validation is not
>   needed.